# Interrupt causes protection faults

Tags: linux, architecture, x86-64, interrupt, systems-programming

I have a oneline C program:

```
int main(){asm volatile ("INT $0x06"::);}
```

Once compiled, I execute it by

```
sudo ./a.out
```

However, it does not throw invalid instruction error (as expected, since `0x06` is invalid instruction interrupt). Instead, in `dmesg`, it switches to general protection trap...

```
[ 2898.849785] traps: a.out[2534] general protection ip:4004f1 sp:7fffa949c8f0 error:32 in a.out[400000+1000]
```

My question is: what is the right way to throw an interrupt in kernel space?

My platform is Ubuntu 14.04 on linux 3.13 and x86_64.